# How can I convert the timer from counting back in seconds to count back in minutes and seconds?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have numericUpDown1 that when I set its value it's saving the value in options text file:

```
private void numericUpDown1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Options_DB.Set_Radar_Images_Time(numericUpDown1.Value);
        }
```

timer1 interval set to 1000ms in the form1 designer.

In timer1 tick event I have:

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           numbers_radar = Convert.ToInt64(numericUpDown1.Value);
        }
```

Now I want to assign the timer tick event to: label21.Text and display the minutes counting down.
If I set the numericUpDown1 to 10 so it will count down 10 minutes.

The format should be like: minutes:seconds (00:00).

And each time the timer get to 1 it should call this method: fileDownloadRadar();
Each time when it's get to 1 the timer should be reset to the numericUpDown1 value and start over again counting back and each time in the end to call the method fileDownloadRadar();

The numericUpDown1 is set to minimum 5 and maximum 60

EDIT

Now i tried this code but i don't see anything change on label21 when starting the timer.
And minutes is starting as 0 but should be in this case 29(value of numericUpDown1).

And should i check if minutes and seconds == 1 or == 0 ? What's more logic 1 or 0 ?

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            numOfMinutes = Convert.ToInt32(numericUpDown1.Value);
            int seconds = numOfMinutes % 60;
            int minutes = numOfMinutes / 60;
            seconds --;
            string time = minutes + ":" + seconds;
            label21.Text = time;
            if (seconds == 1)
            {
                minutes --;
            }
            if (minutes == 1 && seconds == 1)
            {
                numOfMinutes = Convert.ToInt32(numericUpDown1.Value);
                fileDownloadRadar();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could better use a TimeSpan object and start as follows.

declare a TimeSpan variable in your object (thus a private field):

```
private TimeSpan span;
```

Just below the code where you start the timer, initialize the span variable:

```
timer1.Start(); // this should exist somewhere
TimeSpan span = new TimeSpan(0, numericUpDown1.Value, 0);
```

In your timer event handler, write this code:

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    span = span.Subtract(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1));
    label21.Text = span.ToString(@"mm\:ss");

    if (span.TotalSeconds < 1)
    {
        span = new TimeSpan(0, numericUpDown1.Value, 0);
        fileDownloadRadar();
    }
}
```

I'm not sure what you want in the if statement, but I hope this will help you further.